# keyup event with wrong input val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In a script that capture keyup envent I get the wrong value of the input feild.

```
 $("#country-name").keyup(function () {

    if ($(this).val().length > 1 ) {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }
 });
```

In a input text if I enter <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> then I select both letter and enter quickly <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>r</kbd> I got one log `br` but 2 log `gr`

How can I avoid `$(this).val()` being update too quickly?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to introduce a delay to account for the person typing.

```
var t;
$("#country-name").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
      if (value.length > 1 ) {
        console.log(value);
      }
    }, 500);
});
```

[**Example on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/9jrRu/)

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a local variable like such:

```
$("#country-name").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value.length > 1 ) {
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thread safe would implicate using multiple threads. But it's true that the `val()` doesn't retain the same value within a function scope. That wouldn't make any sense anyway, since you're requesting the value again.

Comment: It is better but still does not work I guess in certain circumstance

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle of the use case? (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Oh! I just realize why. In fact since the keytyping is close I am not even made a keyup event for the first character.